# Hibernate Many-To-One Relationship without Foreign Key but with reverse foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have the following DB:

```
CREATE TABLE car_owner (
  car_owner_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  car_id_fk int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (car_owner_id),
  KEY car_owner_car_fk_idx (car_id_fk),
  CONSTRAINT car_owner_car_fk FOREIGN KEY (car_id_fk) REFERENCES car (car_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE car (
   car_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   car_type varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   car_plates varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (car_id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And In the java model:

For CarOwner I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car_owner")
@NamedQuery(name="CarOwner.findAll", query="SELECT co FROM CarOwner co")
public class CarOwner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="car_owner_id")
    private Integer carOwnerId;
.....

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Car
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "car_id")
    private List<Car> cars;
```

And for Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
@NamedQuery(name="Car.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Car c")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="car_id")
    private Integer carId;
......

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to car_owner
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_owner_id")
    private CarOwner carOwner;
```

The problem here is that Hibernate can't relate the tables and goes creating new `car_id` and `car_owner_id` columns in car table automatically.

Can anybody help in finding the right combination in the model to relate the tables appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@JoinColumn` should be in owner of relationship (in a one to many it's the many side that's regarded the owner).

So I will modify this in `car`

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "car_owner_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private CarOwner carOwner;
```

And this in `CarOwner`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "carOwner")
 private List<Car> cars;
```

---

As a side note I would also not be using `EAGER` but that has got nothing to do with question.

---

Both tables knowing about each other is called Bi-directional relationship.This happens when each table has a key to other table. This is what your java code is expecting.Your tables in database however have a uni-directional relationship. Meaning one table knows about the other but not both. Your `car_owner` knows about `car` because of foriegn key `CONSTRAINT car_owner_car_fk FOREIGN KEY` but your `car` does not have any idea about `car_owner` both are perfectly valid.

Now the problem is that in your Java code you are treating it as a bi-directional relationship.

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to car_owner
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "car_owner_id")
 private CarOwner carOwner;
```

but car does not have `car_owner_id` why are you treating it a Bi-directional relationship.

Now either update database to make them bi or change java code.

Comment: I get this exception:    `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'car0_.car_owner_id' in 'field list'
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`

Comment: because in fact `car` doesn't have a column named `car_owner_id` . . . nothing solved . . .

Comment: I did not pay enough attention to the SQL Ginger. Well it is not bi-directional then.Thats the fundamental flaw.

Comment: Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Basically you will either have to add that column in database or make it unidirectional.There is no other possibility. In database Car does  know about owner.

Comment: But why it works when the second table has a foreign key to the first and not the vice versa, what's the difference?